# 3d elements on a 2d HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, 3d, three.js, 2d

I am doing a 2d game using `HTML5` Canvas and I want to add 3d characters to the 2D canvas.

Would it be a good (or even possible) solution to use `THREE.js` on separate "hidden" canvases, 1 for each 3d character. But then, draw those '3d' canvases on to the main 2d canvas?

Can I draw `webGL` canvases on a '2d' canvas?

Any potential problems with this solution?

Any "best practices" would be violated?

My intuition is that this is a good way to go.

Comment: Are you trying to do a 2.5D game? Won't it be simpler to export the 3D character as png and draw it on the 2D canvas?

Comment: Yes it would. But my designer wants it to be 3D so that he does not have to export same sprites in different angels. So, i am trying to find a compromise.

Comment: Hmmmm... ok... Then better do it in `WebGL`(it can draw in 2D too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webgl uses `webgl` contexts, not `2d`. Why do you need different canvas layers ? Anyway you could do it by setting a transparent background yes, but that would be heavy for your browser. What you can do inside a single `webgl` context (maybe on top of an other `2d` context you would need) is to render different scenes with your different characters, the result would be identical

Comment: To answer your question. Wouldn't having 2 canvas layers be the only option if one canvas uses a '2d' context, and the other uses 'webgl' context? They don't mix together, so they would have to be on different canvases. Right?

Comment: yep, one `webgl` context (=canvas), with a transparent background, for you 3d characters, rendered in different scenes. On top (css) of a `2d` context with what you need. The best would still be only one canvas, so you add a plane behind your characters and render your picture/landscape/whatever on it. The render result, code, logic, practice would all be better.

Comment: @Karandawov if the answer is correct you can validate it

Comment: no worries. i did not forgot :) Was just waiting for more possible answers, and fell asleep :)